# SSRS Get Previous Row Group Values in Tablix Groupings

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, cumulative-sum

I have a tablix which has a group A, B, C.
The dataset has values for A, values for B, and values for C.

Inside I have a grouping with details.
So:

```
A
 v1 1
 v2 2
sub 3
B
 v3 3
sub 3
C
 v4 4
 v5 5
sub 9
```

sub is the subtotals of the details in the group.
How can I grab the sets of details from A and add them to B, but not C?
Before I did an if statement and used "Running Total", which helped for numbers and summing, but what about details, such as strings?

Otherwise, all the data is in the dataset. If you're nested in a grouping, is there still a way to get all the data of a dataset and ignore the group on?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by adding the strings from A to those from B?   Concatenating?

Comment: Yes, like + them together, but in a runningvalue sort of way.